# Media Queries: shrink nav font size in shrinking desktops while enlarge it in mobile

Tags: media-queries

I'm a bit confused

On top of the home page I have a logo that resizes fine with the screen width and it is left positioned

At right I have the nav bar (bootstrap)

While shrinking the the page, the various media queries I've set, are working as expected, since I have my custom CSS that overrides the

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default
```

and so at

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

I set the nav.navbar.navbar-default' font-size to 0.8em

But this creates me one behavior:
when the menu toggles to the mobile version, obviously the nav bar font-size remains 0.8em, as stated by media query rule I've set above.

The question is:
how to increase again the font-size to 1em when at the mobile media queries sizes?

I'm confused, since, e.g., I've tried this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
nav.navbar.navbar-default {
font-size: 1em;}
}
```

but it overrides the previous treshold and the nav bar font-size goes back to 1em also where it was previously correctly displaying at 0.8

Obviously I miss some knowledge :-) about media query

Can you kindly hint about how to make this kind of setup

screen widths --> font sizes

major than 1024 --> 1.0em

minor than 1024 major than 768 --> 0.8em

minor than 768/767 (or where bootstrap toggles to the mobile menu) again --> 1em

thank you for your kind help :-)

Answer (score 0):

As is the nature of CSS, the latter media query will override the earlier one. You need to either include min and max-widths to a query or find/add a class name for the mobile menu and use that to draw the font-size rule from.